# Envio de dados com ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um *chat online* que funciona com *ajax* e *PHP*. Porém, estranhamente, quando eu digito somente uma interrogação (`?`) e envio o *jQuery*, retorna-me um erro no console. O *ajax* entra no `error()` e a interrogação (`?`) é inserida no banco, porém com uns caracteres estranhos tipo:

> ```
> jQuery33106296323571939269_1534100132138.
> ```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#envia_chat_id').keyup(function(e){
                    if(e.which === 13 & $('#envia_chat_id').attr('class') === 'envia_chat'){
                        if(trim($('.envia_chat').val()) != ''){
                            var msgenvio = $('.envia_chat').val();
                            var msgrender = msgenvio.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
                            $('#chat_box').append('<div class="msg user_' + $('.time_user').val() + '"><span>'+ $('.nick_user').val() + ': </span>'+ msgrender +'</div)');
                            $('.envia_chat').val('');
                            $('.envia_chat').removeAttr('class');
                            $('#chat_box').scrollTop($('#chat_box').prop("scrollHeight"));
                            $('#envia_chat_id').attr('placeholder','Aguarde para enviar outra...');
                            console.log('msg='+ msgenvio + '&type=enviaMsg&lobby=' + $('.lobbyid').val() + '&time=' + $('.time_user').val() + '&nick=' + $('.nick_user').val());
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'chat.php',
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: 'msg='+ msgenvio + '&type=enviaMsg&lobby=' + $('.lobbyid').val() + '&time=' + $('.time_user').val() + '&nick=' + $('.nick_user').val(),
                            success: function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    $('#envia_chat_id').attr('class','envia_chat');
                                    $('#envia_chat_id').attr('placeholder','Chat...');
                                }, 4000);

                            },
                            error: function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                                $('#chat_box').append('<div class="msg msg_erro">Tente novamente enviar esta mensagem.</div)');
                                $('#chat_box').scrollTop($('#chat_box').prop("scrollHeight"));
                                $('#envia_chat_id').attr('class','envia_chat');
                                $('#envia_chat_id').attr('placeholder','Chat...');
                            }
                            });
                        }

                    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function Erro($texto){
        $array = array('status' => $texto);
        return json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    function Sucesso($texto){
        $array = array('status' => $texto);
        return json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']) and !empty($_SESSION['login_id']) and isset($_POST['type']) and isset($_POST['lobby']) and is_numeric($_POST['lobby']) == true){
        require('connection.php');
        $id = $_SESSION['login_id'];
            $acao = $_POST['type'];
            $id_lobby = (is_numeric($_POST['lobby'])==true) ? $_POST['lobby'] : NULL;
            $tempo_atual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $msg = (isset($_POST['msg'])==true and $_POST['msg'] != '') ? filter_var($_POST['msg'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS) : NULL;
                    $time = (isset($_POST['time']) == true and $_POST['time'] == 'azul' or $_POST['time'] == 'laranja' or $_POST['time'] == 'ambos') ? $_POST['time'] : NULL;
                    $nick = (isset($_POST['nick']) == true) ? $_POST['nick'] : NULL;
                    if(trim($msg) != NULL and $time != NULL and $nick != NULL){
                        $insere_msg = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO chat (id_user, content, id_lobby, timestamp, time, nick) VALUES ('$id', '$msg', '$id_lobby', '$tempo_atual', '$time', '$nick')");
                        if($insere_msg === true){
                        echo Sucesso('success');
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo Erro('erro_null');
                    }
    }else{
        echo Erro('erro_faltam');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Dica: use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` apenas em desenvolvimento. Em produção, o custo de exibir o json formatado pode ser grande, devido aos espaços e quebras de linhas adicionados ao retorno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao enviar o caractere `?` sozinho numa das variáveis do `data` (concatenando as variáveis em forma de string URL, como está fazendo) o jQuery irá tratar a URL como JSONP e irá registrar um callback quando o Ajax retornar a requisição. Como não foi indicado nenhum callback (até porque não era essa a intenção devido a ao `dataType` ser "JSON"), irá resultar no erro mencionado, tal como:

> parsererror Error: jQuery33100166499243115803_1534312585291 was not
>   called

O jQuery criou e tentou chamar um callback `jQuery33100166499243115803_1534312585291` que não existe.

Envie os dados no `data` em forma de objeto, e não em forma de string URL:

```
data: {
   msg: msgenvio,
   type: 'enviaMsg',
   lobby: $('.lobbyid').val(),
   time: $('.time_user').val(),
   nick: $('.nick_user').val()
},
```

Comment: Essa forma de enviar no data é a melhor forma? Ou somente para este tipo de erro?

Comment: Acredito ser a melhor forma.

Answer (score 1):

Dados de formulário `POST` quando são enviado para o servidor, geralmente possuem por padrão a formatação `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. E, como o próprio nome sugere, os dados são codificados como dados de URL.

Caracteres como `?` e `&` são caracteres especiais numa url, e os mesmos, se forem mandados como conteúdo literal, precisam ser codificados.

Para fazer isso, existem duas formas:

- Usar o `data`, como já foi explicado na resposta anterior.
- Usar a função `$.param` para montar os parâmetros da sua url.

Veja como o `$.param` se comporta:

```js
$(function () {

    console.log($.param({question: 'Qual é o seu nome?'}));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Observe que o resultado da chamada de `$.param` fez com que a string passada mudasse completamente. Isso é porque é usado a codificação para url.

Por curiosidade, o jQuery por padrão usa o `$.param` no objeto que você passa como parâmetro para `data` na chamada de `$.ajax`.